# Push Notification Service is not running when the app is not in the background

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a little bit confusing on integrating FCM (Firebase cloud messaging)  push notification on my application.

Normally, Rather than the Intent services other services are not stopped anymore in the middle. I have created my message receiving service by extending to the FirebaseMessagingService as follow

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "NotificationBean Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //This method is responsible for handling notification 
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
     }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

and registered the service on manifest as follow:

```
<service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />   
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

This service is run on when the app is live and running in the background too. But when the app is not in the background the service is not run anymore.

I have registered the service on Main Activity as follow

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // register GCM registration complete receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

        // register new push message receiver
        // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message arrives
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

        // clear the notification area when the app is opened
        NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Let me know anything wrong in my code. (Possibly not) .Why notifications are not running on background. How do I overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found a solution for this issue. The solution is working fine on Huawei mobiles. But not working on Xiomi RedMe note 3. The solutions link is here http://itechify.com/2016/02/01/how-to-fix-missing-push-notifications-on-huawei-smartphones/

Comment: Can't we fixed this programmatically

Answer (score 0):

use your server data or api like this

```
       {
"to" : "deviceToken",

"notification" : {
  "body" : "Pass body here",
  "title" : "Title n",
  "icon" : " icon ",
  "sound" : "notification sound "
}
```

}

//for exa.

```
$fields=array('to'=>fdfdfdfdsfdsdfdfdsfdsfdfdsfd" ,'notification'=>array('title'=>'mytitle','body'=>$title,'click_action'=>'abc','icon'=>'ic_stat_final','sound'=>'default','color'=>'#00aff0'),'data'=>array('ghmid'=>$hgmid,'page'=>$page));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thinks are I am asking from the client side, not in the server part. Event the client side also working perfectly even the app is in the background or on live. The problem is when the app is not running on the backgrounds the push notification is skipped.

Comment: if your app is on background onMessageReceived will not call so you cant handle in client side

Comment: FirebaseMessagingService  class call only when app is open and not in background

Comment: But it is not a intent service, It is a service class. If it is a service class, then it should be serve the application on bacground process via the service class. Otherwise there is no point on we are writing as a service . Correct me if i say aything wrong.

Comment: yes you r correct but i tried same but i diidnt found any helpfull detail i got same solution its working fine also

Comment: my server API call already in the same format you mentioned above.

Comment: it is possible to post your $field

Answer (score 0):

If your data is of type notification ie "Notification"then the onReceived method is not supposed to be get called when app is in background. Though it can be retrived when app comes to foreground. If it is of type data then it will get called.Change your type to "Data" instead of notification. Also when you change the data to type "Data" your getNotification() method may not work and app will get null pointer exception. Server data can also be of type where it has both "data" and "notification".

Answer (score 0):

change json object key from notification to data

e.g

```
{
“to”: “device_ID/fcmID”,
“notification”: {
“body”: “great match!”,
“title”: “Portugal vs. Denmark”,
“icon”: “myicon”
}
}
```

change to

```
{
“to”: “device_ID/fcmID”,
“data”: {
“Nick”: “abc”,
“body”: “nfjwhhwruguig”,
“Room”: “cnrughwriugg”
},
}
```

Client app receives a data message in `onMessageReceived()` irrespective of the fact whether app is in foreground or background.

ref: https://blog.talentica.com/2017/01/20/firebase-cloud-messaging-in-android/